# Terraform: How to pass Elastic Beanstalk environment's coupled database parameters to the environment resource itself?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform-provider-aws

Im provisioning a AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment including a coupled RDS database using `settings` options. The deployed application requires this very db host. How would I achieve this?

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "eb_env" {
  name                = "app-dev"
  application         = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.tftest.name
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.5.6 running Docker"

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "HasCoupledDatabase"
    value     = "true"
  }
  .
  .
  .
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
    name      = "DB_HOST"
    value     = ?????????
    resource  = ""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.db.html#environments-cfg-rds-create), these should be available in the environment without any additional configuration:

[image]